# Problems while trying to insert API DATA in SQL LITE DATABASE

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, sqlite

everyone! So basically I have this problem. I'm trying to make a request to a `zipcode API` on Brazil, but the data is showed on the `JSON` format. What I have to do, it's to take this information from the `API` and put it on a `SQLlite database`. But, somehow I don't know how to do it. I tried to use this code:

```
import requests
import sqlite3
import json
print('Identifying the ZIP CODE')
CEPC = input('Please type the zipcode:')
Requisicao = requests.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/%7B%7D/json/%27.format(CEPC))
print(Requisicao.json())
#Database
con = sqlite3.connect('CEPS.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Requisicao')
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Requisicao (cep int(8), data json)")
for Requisicao1 in Requisicao:
cur.execute("insert into Requisicao values (8, 5)",
          [Requisicao1['cep'], json.dumps(Requisicao1)])
cur.commit()
cur.close()
```

It's all working when I try to make the request to the API, but when I try to insert the data on the database I just can't. When it come to this code part:

```
for or Requisicao1 in Requisicao:
cur.execute("insert into Requisicao values (8, 5)",
      [Requisicao1['cep'], json.dumps(Requisicao1)])



It gives me the error: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str.
```

Examples of zipcodes are: `09931080, 05565000`.

**The outpout to the zipcode example is:**

```
{
  "cep": "05565-000",
  "logradouro": "Avenida General Asdrúbal da Cunha",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Jardim Arpoador",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004",
  "ddd": "11",
  "siafi": "7107"
}
```

This is the output when I try to get the request.

Comment: Can you add some sample zipcodes to the question, in particular ones that will return multiple results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code in the question:

- the url is invalid: it seems the path has been before formatting; however this is presumably a transcription mistake, otherwise it would cause an error immediately
- the code loops over the response (`Requisicao`). This is operating on the raw request, which is not useful here.  Perhaps, the intention is to handle the API returning multiple zip codes?  As we only have examples we don't need to loop.
- in the query statement, `values (8, 5)` would cause `8` and `5` to be inserted in each row.  It should be `values (?, ?)` to insert the values that you provide (this is know as parameter substitution).
- the connection should be committed, not the cursor.

Based on the above comments, the insertion code would look like this:

```py
Requisicao1 = Requisicao.json()
cur.execute("insert into Requisicao values (?, ?)",
            [Requisicao1['cep'], json.dumps(Requisicao1)])
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

Comment: Could you please check my new edit? The code is working, but I need to insert more columns

Comment: @Rui3144 No - you can't change your question once it's been answered.  Ask a new question.  And roll back your edit to the question.

Comment: Oh, I'm Sorry I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are using doesn't appear to match the one [here](https://viacep.com.br/) so I've replaced it in the following code.

I've also removed the loop as neither example zipcode returns multiple records - if there are zipcodes that do please add one.

Note the data to insert needs to be a tuple, not a list.

Also, for multiple records you would use `executemany` and a list of tuples.

```py
import requests
import sqlite3
import json

CEPC = input("Please type the zipcode:")

print("Identifying the ZIP CODE")

Requisicao = requests.get(f"https://viacep.com.br/ws/{CEPC}/json")

if Requisicao.status_code == 200:
    data = Requisicao.json()
    # Database
    con = sqlite3.connect("CEPS.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Requisicao")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Requisicao (cep int(8), data json)")

    cur.execute("insert into Requisicao values (?, ?)", (data["cep"], json.dumps(data)))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code {Requisicao.status_code} ")
```

Comment: your code it's also working, could you please me help me out again? Please check my edit

Comment: The code it's no inserting values to multiple columns, I had to change the code